# Create Button in CRM 2016 Form without a Field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, dynamics-crm

I had to create a button inside a lookup field i have followed this page 
http://bharathknight.blogspot.com/2015/03/create-button-inside-form-using.html  i have added a event onchange the lookup value but the first alert is hitted but the second none and no button is displayed pleaase help me i'm stucked here

```
function createButton() { 
      alert("createButton");
        var atrname = "xxxx";
        if (document.getElementById(atrname ) != null) {
        var fieldId = "field" + atrname ;

            var elementId = document.getElementById(atrname + "_d");
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.style.width = "20%";
            div.style.textAlign = "right";
            div.style.display = "inline";

            childDiv = elementId.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
            childDiv.style.display = "none";

            elementId.appendChild(div, elementId );
            div.innerHTML = '<button id="' + fieldId + '"  type="button" style="margin-left: 4px; width: 50%;" >CRM Save Button</button>';
            document.getElementById(atrname).style.width = "80%";
            document.getElementById(fieldId ).onclick = function () { OnClickFunction(); };

    }
}

function OnClickFunction() {

    alert("clicked!");
}
```

Comment: **First:** This Line seems wrong, the function should only have one parameter `elementId.appendChild(div, elementId );`.  **Second:** why dont you set `<button id="' + fieldId + '"  type="button" style="margin-left: 4px; width: 50%;" onclick="OnClickFunction()">`, if code-style isn't important.

Comment: @winner_joiner i found this link i think its helpful but also the button doesn' t show up http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2015/06/create-button-in-crm-form-javascript.html

Comment: Check the console, for errors, and maybe set some `console.info`(or if you prefere alert) statments in the code, to see:  what is the value of `elementId`, `fieldId`, `document.getElementById(fieldId)`, if this doesnt flush out the error, you must post more code(maybe the html), because its abit little to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the introduction of turbo forms, things have changed a bit. If you want to access DOM, use document's parent element.

```
function createButton() {
var atrname = 'foobar';
if (window.parent.document.getElementById(atrname) != null) {
    var fieldId = 'field' + atrname;
    var elementId = window.parent.document.getElementById(atrname + '_d');
    var div = window.parent.document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '20%';
    div.style.textAlign = 'right';
    div.style.display = 'inline';

    var childDiv = elementId.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    childDiv.style.display = 'none';

    elementId.appendChild(div, elementId);
    div.innerHTML = '<button id="' + fieldId + '"  type="button" style="margin-left: 4px; width: 50%;" >CRM Save Button</button>';
    window.parent.document.getElementById(atrname).style.width = '80%';
    window.parent.document.getElementById(fieldId).onclick = function () { OnClickFunction(); };

    }
}
```